# How do I start Atom editor on dev mode?

Tags: atom-editor

I want to Modify `ex-mode` package

I tried below commands, but `atom -d .` does not work.
This command does not open atom window.
How can I open atom with dev mode?

Commands:

```
export ATOM_REPOS_HOME=~/github/atom
apm dev ex-mode
cd ~/github/atom/ex-mode
atom -d . # this command does not work
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `atom --dev .` you just open the folder that you are in in dev mode.
You will se a red message on the middle of the status bar.

If you want to modify the package you can copy into `~/.atom/dev/packages/<package-name>` and you will be able to enable/disable both.